# Can neutrinos really travel faster than the speed of light?

Tags: faster-than-light, neutrinos

A few years ago scientists found that neutrinos were going faster than the speed of light. Then they found some problem with the calculations. I read an article that was made this year about faster than light neutrinos. I'm not sure if the journalist is ignorant or if they found that the neutrinos really were going faster.

Comment: You may want to check more sources before asking a question like this. Kudos to you for checking here, though. Assuming you're talking about the OPERA experiment, the answer is that there was indeed an instrumental error.

Comment: What we can say is that, so far, FTL neutrinos have not been observed. That means, that we have to keep looking for neutrinos and other particles that may exceed the speed of light. It would be a rather unexpected discovery, but in science one can not rule out anything with absolute certainty. The proper answer is therefor always one that makes a distinction between what we know (because of the experiments and observations that we have done) and an absolute answer that is usually part of some theoretical framework, which, of course, is always an extrapolation.

Comment: [Jim Al-Khalili](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Al-Khalili) said at the time on BBC T.V. that he would eat his hat if this result were to be confirmed.